# How to execute the EF Core queries generated to SQL that is written in console from the logger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

With the middle we can register the logger to generate the SQL queries in relation to the EF core

```
public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<LegalRegTechDbContext> builder, string connectionString, int commandTimeout)
{
    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
           .LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
}
```

The above configuration generates the below query for example

```
Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__ef_filter__p_0='?' (DbType = Boolean),
    @__ef_filter__p_1='?' (DbType = Boolean)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='120']
      SELECT TOP(1) [c].[Id], [c].[Arguments], [c].[ClientTemplateTenantId], [c].[CreationTime], [c].[CreatorUserId], [c].[DeleterUserId], [c].[DeletionTime], [c].[IsDeleted], [c].[JobStatus], [c].[LastModificationTime], [c].[LastModifierUserId], [c].[TenantId]
      FROM [CopyClientTemplateBackgroundJobLog] AS [c]
      WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_0 = CAST(1 AS bit) OR [c].[IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)) AND @__ef_filter__p_1 = CAST(1 AS bit) AND [c].[JobStatus] = 4
      ORDER BY [c].[CreationTime]
```

If I copy and paste this query it won't execute in SQL Server because of the parameter not declared:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@__ef_filter__p_0"

How can I make it to run in SQL Server from logs copy and paste?

Since this is a simple query in which I make make a change, however with the big queries it will be difficult to do it.

I am using Mac so SQL Server Management Studio and Profiler are not available

Comment: Look at [ToQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-7.0) method. In some cases, it will help you.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov is there a way to use ToQueryString method inside the LogTo(), because I don't want to write on each line this code var sqlQuery = query.ToQueryString();
        Console.WriteLine($"Generated SQL query: {sqlQuery}");

Comment: Just insert your own declaration, and initialise the variables like; `declare @__ef_filter__p_0 bit, @__ef_filter__p_1 bit   select @__ef_filter__p_0=1, @__ef_filter__p_1=0   SELECT TOP(1)...`

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query generated by EF Core contains parameters that are not declared in the query. You can use SQL Server Profiler to capture the SQL queries generated by EF Core and run them in SQL Server Management Studio. However, since you are using Mac and SQL Server Management Studio and Profiler are not available, you can try using the InterpolatedStringHandler class to generate the SQL query with the parameters.

Here is an example:

```
var query = context.CopyClientTemplateBackgroundJobLogs
    .Where(c => c.JobStatus == 4 && c.IsDeleted == false)
    .OrderBy(c => c.CreationTime)
    .Take(1)
    .ToQueryString();

var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = query;

foreach (var parameter in 
context.CopyClientTemplateBackgroundJobLogs.ToSqlParameters())
{
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}

var result = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
```

Comment: I don't want to write .ToQueryString(); on each ef calls

Answer (score 0):

Ef core use Parameterized queries to help prevent SQL injection attacks. By using placeholders for parameter values, EF Core ensures that user input is properly sanitized and treated as data rather than executable SQL code. This significantly reduces the risk of malicious input compromising your application's database.

So here `@__ef_filter__p_0` and `@__ef_filter__p_1` are  placeholders, In default EF core will hidden the value of placeholders with `?`, just like `[Parameters=[@__ef_filter__p_0='?' (DbType = Boolean), @__ef_filter__p_1='?' (DbType = Boolean)]` If you wanna show these values  you can configure like:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine).EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        }
```

Then in your dbcontext, It will log sql like:

```
 Executed DbCommand (55ms) [Parameters=[@__i_0='20'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[Age], [m].[Name], [m].[Salary]
      FROM [myDemos] AS [m]
      WHERE [m].[Age] = @__i_0
      ORDER BY [m].[Salary]
```

This can only be used in dev and test environment.

With this configuration, you still need to replace the placeholder by yourself, But you can replace them with given values. I don't find any methods can log sql without placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

In EF Core, we can use different logging methods, including via [Interception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/#interception).
[Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) - documentation.

```
public class SqlLoggingInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(
        DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        foreach (SqlParameter p in command.Parameters)
        {
            string type = null;
            string size = null;
            string value = null;

            if (p.SqlDbType == SqlDbType.Int)
            {
                type = "int";
                value = p.Value.ToString();
            }
            else if (p.SqlDbType == SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            {
                type = "nvarchar";
                value = $"N'{p.Value}'";
                if (p.Size > 0)
                {
                    size = $"({p.Size})";
                }
            }

            string s = $"DECLARE {p.ParameterName} {type}{size} = {value}";
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText);

        return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }
}
```

Register our interceptor in `OnConfiguring` method:

```
optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new SqlLoggingInterceptor());
```

I wrote only a small piece of code. There is a lot of work to be done.
You need to override the other methods of the interceptor.
You need to write the code for declaring the remaining `SqlDbType` types.